# DELPHI: Declare HTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute in TComponent

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2005

Using Delphi 2005, I have created a test app (using a TForm) to test a SOAP API.  Unfortunately this API has declared some enums (Application, System and Terminal) which are reserved by Delphi.  I renamed the enums in the SOAP file (_Application, _Terminal and _System) and was able to write OnBeforeExecute and OnAfterExecute methods to replace these renamed enums with the original names before and after submitting.

I am now trying to incorporate this into my larger project and would like to capture all the code for this SOAP API in a class file (no form).  With my tester app I added a THTTPRIO object to the form (from the Tool Palette) and could easily set the OnBeforeExecute and OnAfterExecute methods in the Object Inspector.  Now using the class (a TComponent) I cannot add the THTTPRIO object using Tool Palette like I did with the form.  I tried to create the THTTPRIO object via code but am getting some errors.

I get the error `E2009 incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ'` on  `FEPS_HTTPRIO.OnAfterExecute := HTTPRIOAfterExecute;` (see code below)

Why do I get the error on this but not on   `FEPS_HTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute := HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;` and how can I implement these two methods within my class?

Here is how I created the THTTPRIO via code:

```
unit c_MoSh;

interface

uses classes, forms, Windows, SysUtils, c_MoShAPI, InvokeRegistry, controls;

Type

  TMoSh = class(TComponent)
  private
    ...
    procedure HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string;
                                    var SOAPRequest: WideString);
    procedure HTTPRIOAfterExecute(const MethodName: string;
                                    var SOAPResponse: TStream);

  ...

constructor TMoSh.Create();
begin
  FEPS_HTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(self);
  FEPS_HTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute := HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
  FEPS_HTTPRIO.OnAfterExecute := HTTPRIOAfterExecute;       <-- Error line

end;

procedure TMosquitoShield.HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string;
                                    var SOAPRequest: WideString);
var
  tmpString: TStringList;
begin

  try

    SOAPRequest := StringReplace(SOAPRequest,'<ReversalType>_Application','<ReversalType>Application',[RfReplaceAll]);
    SOAPRequest := StringReplace(SOAPRequest,'<ReversalType>_System','<ReversalType>System',[RfReplaceAll]);
    SOAPRequest := StringReplace(SOAPRequest,'<CardholderPresentCode>NotPresent2','<CardholderPresentCode>NotPresent',[RfReplaceAll]);
    SOAPRequest := StringReplace(SOAPRequest,'<DeviceInputCode>NotUsed3','<DeviceInputCode>NotUsed',[RfReplaceAll]);

  except
    on ER : ERemotableException do
      ShowMessage(ER.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + ER.FaultDetail + ' :: '
                    + ER.Message);

    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message);
  end;

end;

procedure TMosquitoShield.HTTPRIOAfterExecute(const MethodName: string;
                                    var SOAPResponse: TStream);
var
  tmpString: TStringList;
begin

  try
    tmpString := TStringList.Create;
    SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
    tmpString.LoadFromStream(SOAPResponse);

    tmpString.Text := StringReplace(tmpString.Text,'Application','_Application',[RfReplaceAll]);
    tmpString.Text := StringReplace(tmpString.Text,'System','_System',[RfReplaceAll]);
    tmpString.Text := StringReplace(tmpString.Text,'<PASSUpdaterOption>Null','<PASSUpdaterOption>Null2',[RfReplaceAll]);
    tmpString.Text := StringReplace(tmpString.Text,'<TransactionSetupMethod>Null','<TransactionSetupMethod>Null3',[RfReplaceAll]);
    tmpString.Text := StringReplace(tmpString.Text,'<Device>Null','<Device>Null4',[RfReplaceAll]);
    tmpString.Text := StringReplace(tmpString.Text,'<ConsentCode>NotUsed','<ConsentCode>NotUsed2',[RfReplaceAll]);
    tmpString.Text := StringReplace(tmpString.Text,'<DeviceInputCode>NotUsed','<DeviceInputCode>NotUsed3',[RfReplaceAll]);

    SOAPResponse.Position := 0;
    tmpString.SaveToStream(SOAPResponse);

  except
    on ER : ERemotableException do
      ShowMessage(ER.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + ER.FaultDetail + ' :: '
                    + ER.Message);

    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message);
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method signature has to match the signature of the event type exactly. Remove `var` before `SOAPResponse` parameter in your `HTTPRIOAfterExecute` method.

As for the name conflicts you describe, you can avoid them by prefixing code elements (enumeration members, variables, types etc) with the unit name: `SOAP_API.Application` - for SOAP enumeration, and `Forms.Application` for Delphi `Application` global.

Comment: Thank you so much!  No idea how that got added to the method.

Comment: +1 for reminding me of the unit name prefix; I encountered the same 'reserved name' issue some time ago and used the _ trick, but your solution is better.